Sphinx not including docstring of a module using automodule directive
I have the following content in __init__.py file of a module called src:
"""
.. automodule:: src
   :synopsis: Model-View-Controller architecture
"""

The following content in index.rst:
.. Lab documentation master file, created by
   sphinx-quickstart on Sat Jun 15 14:26:03 2024.
   You can adapt this file completely to your liking, but it should at least
   contain the root `toctree` directive.

Welcome to Lab's documentation!
===============================

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:

   business_description
   architecture_description


Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`

And the following content in architecture_description.rst:
Architecture Description
========================

.. automodule:: src
    :synopsis:

Everything works fine, but the src module synopsis which doesn't show in the documentation.
What am I doing wrong?

The automodule directive does not have a synopsis option. That option is available on the py:module directive.
